# How to query to capture recency and scale in one query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I've built a query that calculates the number of ids from a table, per url_count.

```
with cte as (
  select id, count(distinct.url) url_count
  from table
  group by id
)

select sum(if(url_count >= 1,1,0) scale
from cte
union all
select sum(if(url_count >= 2,1,0) scale
from cte
union all
select sum(if(url_count >= 3,1,0) scale
from cte
union all
select sum(if(url_count >= 4,1,0) scale
from cte
union all
select sum(if(url_count >= 5,1,0) scale
from cte
```

The query above says; "Give me the list of ids and the number of urls they each go to, then accumulate the number of ids who have gone to [1-5] or more urls"

It's ofc a tedious method, but works and outputs something like;

```
---------
| scale |
---------
|1213432|
|867554 |
|523523 |
|342232 |
|145889 |
---------
```

From this table, I also have a date field on the last 5 days which I'm working on adding into this query. Thus lies the challenge; Trying to add a second layer of information to the query; i.e. Recency. Been working on multiple approaches to building a query that outputs all the combinations of different scales, per the date.

The sort of output I've imagined is a pivot table which presents something like;

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   date   | url_co1 | url_co2 | url_co3 | url_co4 | url_co5|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-01-05| 1213432 | 1112321 | 984332  | 632131  | 234124 |
|2020-01-04| 1012131 |  934242 | 867554  | 533242  | 134234 |
|    ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...  |
|    ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...  |
|    ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...   |   ...  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where url_co[1-5] represents the number of ids that visited [1-5] or more urls and dates gives up the date that volume was captured. No idea how to write that because once I query:

```
with cte as (
  select id, date, count(distinct.url) url_count
  from table
  group by id, date
)
```

I've aggregated to per id, per date, which therefore something goes wrong. =/

Hope that all made sense!

Please, please help! I would appreciate some guidance.

There must be a methodology for getting the combination of volumes per recency that I've missed!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really follow the full question, but the first query can be simplified to:

```
select url_count, count(*) as this_count,
       sum(url_count) over (order by url_count desc) as descending_count
from (select id, count(distinct url) as url_count
      from table
      group by id
     ) t
group by url_count
order by url_count;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help at all.